# Initialization Error for Junit in Eclipse

Tags: junit, cucumber, hamcrest

I have configured Cucumber Maven project and getting Initialization error while executing my RunTest.java file:

```
package annotation;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith; 
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber; 
@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}) 
public class RunTest { }
```

I had included hamcrest-library files too but still I don't know what I have left out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code instead...

```
package annotation;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber" })
public class RunTest {
}
```

Two `import statements` were wrong. `Cucumber.Options` was not correct it is `CucumberOptions`. format is now deprecated, use plugin.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your valuable feedback. when i use plugin, am getting error message like 'The attribute plugin is undefined for the annotation type CucumberOptions'

Comment: Upgrade the cucumber version.

Comment: I had updated the cucumber version even still am getting the same error message.. What shall i do now?

Comment: Add the error and stacktrace if any in your question.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(Ljava/util/Properties;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at cucumber.runtime.junit.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:32)
 at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:56)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilde

Comment: Also i get the below message as well: 
at Cucumber.runtime.junit.RuntimeoptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:32)
at Cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:56)
at Java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)